# Differences between Einstein Gravity and classical Supergravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, supersymmetry, supergravity

Given that the main difference of super-spacetime and spacetime is in the Grassmann dimensions, I want to know about the main differences in terms of results and features or modifications, between **CLASSICAL** [SUGRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergravity) in 3+1 dimensions and GR?

Comment: This seems to be the subject of Isenberg _et al._ [Classical Supergravity](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-009-6446-4_8), but there may be more modern references.

Comment: What predictions does it make?  Does it deviate from GR in testable circumstances?  Maybe it is just a bad wiki page, but the article itself is horribly imprecise about any of this.  Just maths.

Comment: @m4r35n357 As the "horrible article" states on page 176, the deviations require for consistency: "(1) The connection field must contain torsion" which _is_ testable (and does not appear to be supported by experimental tests). If I were a better experimentalist, I'm sure I could think of a test for the other condition for consistency of SUGRA that "(2) the components of the spinor field must anticommute."

Comment: @AlexNelson Comprehension: "horribly _imprecise_ article"

Comment: @AlexNelson Do these corrections to the GR connection, the torsion in fact, appears as a quantum semi-classical correction that is suppressed exponentially in sth etc. or an absolutely classical correction?

Comment: @BastamTajik Without these conditions, it'd be impossible to have classical supergravity. They are required classically, not semi classically, etc.

Comment: [Canonical] Quantum Supergravity is worse, it won't have bosonic solutions (and thus cannot recover "vanilla" quantum gravity solutions).